# Apache - Wordpress unable to load after moving it to another directory

Tags: apache-2.2, wordpress

I had my wordpress files in /var/www/site1.com but i move them in /var/www/site2.com and now wordpress can't load. If i open the home page it just show something that look like basic html page with some titles and few links but the links are not working. If i click on the LogIn link it shows:  `/wp-login.php was not found on this server.`

I guess this is a issue with broken paths but i am not sure how to fix it.

I also cleared the mysql cache with the commands: `FLUSH TABLES;` and  `RESET QUERY CACHE;` but this didn't help.

How to resolve this issue?

EDIT: The problem was in wordpres database. I login in phpmyadmin and in the table `wp_options` i changed the path for `siteurl` and `home` to the new wordpress directory. 
But i don't know if this can be done without using phpmyadmin. It will be good if this can be done by modifing some of the wordpress configuration files.

Answer (score 0):

Apache 2.2 will often use the sites-available directory with a configuration file that points to your root directory. Is this what you modified or did you add another file to the sites-available directory or did you just create rename the directory? If you renamed, you need to edit the appropriate file in the sites-available directory.

Comment: The new wordpress location is here: `/var/www/site2.com`. The virtual host file is here: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/site2.com`. The content of site2.com file is this: 

 `<VirtualHost *:80>  
        ServerName site2.com
        DocumentRoot /var/www/site2.com
</VirtualHost>`

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Apache configuration updates, you'll need to update wp internals also. Please refer to http://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL for detailed  steps. Basically you'll need to add a couple of defines to wp-config.php file with new url.